# I can connect to ws://localhost:8088/ari/events?api_key=user:user&app=hello-world, but i can't connect to ws://localhost:8088/ws. Why?

Tags: javascript, websocket, laravel-8, asterisk-ari, phpari

I am using laravel and javascript to presend live data of a call center dashboard. How can I control the realtime data with laravel endpoints and websockets, I do not want to access asterisk ari with javascript directly but first with laravel and do some calculations and process the outcome from ARI then return the outcome from laravel to javascript.

I tried to access the call laravel endpoints with javascript websockets with the specific port 8088 but it returned an error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.